# Родительный падеж числительного пятьсот

Tags: числительные

Постоянно в СМИ читаю и слышу: пятиста книг, семиста шестидесяти тонн и т. п. Насколько я знаю, правильная форма родительного падежа составных числительных пятьсот, шестьсот и т. п. - пятисот, восьмисот... Или я отстала от жизни и утвердились новые нормы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не отстали от жизни. Склоняется это числительное так: И. п. - пятьсот, Р. п. - пятисот, Д. п. - пятистам, В. п. - пятьсот, Т. п. - пятьюстами, П. п. - пятистах. Числительное *пятьсот* возникло из сочетания числительного *пять* с числительным *сто* в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: *пять сътъ*. Каждая часть этого сложного слова склоняется по-своему: *пять* - как существительные ж. р. III склонения, а *сто* имеет форму *сот* в именительном и родительном падеже, в остальных падежах эта часть склоняется как существительные I или II склонения во множественном числе.

Answer (score 1):

В учебнике русского языка для 6 класса 2009 года издания есть таблица:
Падеж           500-900
Именительный    пятьсот
Родительный пятисот
Дательный   пятистам
Винительный пятьсот
Творительный    пятьюстами
Предложный  о пятистах
Следовательно, вариант ПЯТИСОТ ещё не устарел:)) А СМИ сегодня, к сожалению, не образец.

Answer (score 1):

О 765 городах,  в 493 поселках, в 1773 году, в 2016 году, на 1389 километре,
о 269 учащихся, на 74-м году жизни, в 37 квартирах,  нет 777 человек, 958 студентами.

Answer (score 0):

О двухстах двадцати пяти городах, в трехстах сорока девяти поселках, в тысяча восемьсот восемнадцатом году, на тысяча двести сорок втором километре, о четырехстах пятидесяти восьми учащихся, на восьмидесятом году жизни, в девяноста двух квартирах, нет трехсот тридцати трех человек, пятистам пятидесяти восьми студентам.